# Running Socket.IO continuously in Flutter Windows app

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, socket.io

I am developing a Windows software with Flutter and using Socket.IO for real-time communication. I am facing an issue where the Socket.IO connection is closed when the app is closed. I need the connection to remain active even when the app is closed. Here is my current approach:

- I am using the `socket_io_client` package in my Flutter app to connect to the Socket.IO server.
- I have tried running the connection code in a separate isolate, but the connection is still closed when the app is closed.

Is there a way to keep the Socket.IO connection alive even when the Flutter app is closed on Windows?

I expected that by running the Socket.IO connection code in a separate isolate, the connection would remain active even when the Flutter app is closed. However, I found that the connection is still closed when the app is closed.